# Unable to delete files with full permissions

Tags: vb.net, file

I coded a simple function that deletes all files in a directory. All files in my directory (including the directory) have full permission for all users but my function doesn't work and I receive this error: "Access to the path is denied."

**Very important**: This error appears only for the file that I have copied manually from another dir, instead for that files that my program creates and saves, there is no error.

This is my function:

```
Private Sub DeleteFile(ByVal Folder As IO.DirectoryInfo)
   Dim _fl As IO.FileInfo
   For Each _fl In Folder.GetFiles
      _fl.Delete()
   Next
   _fl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you confirm, using the File Explorer and the file properties, that this file has full permissions for everyone? (after copy)

Comment: Is the file marked as Read-Only?

Comment: By the way, you don't really need a loop to delete the content of a directory. DirectoryInfo has a Delete overload that zaps away anything in the directory and the directory itself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.delete?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_Delete_System_Boolean_